# Array into a PHP Soapclient call

Tags: php, web-services, soap-client

I'm using php and Soapclient. I need send next parameters:

```
        <sch:CodConsulta v="5473"/>
        <sch:Parametros>

           <sch:Txt n="Agente" v="aaa"/>
           <sch:Fec n="Fecha" v="2018-01-24"/>
           <sch:Txt n="Sesion" v="0"/>
        </sch:Parametros>
```

I've tried send params like this:

```
$parametros = array(
   "CodConsulta" => array('_' => '',"v" => "5473"),
   "Parametros" => array( 
      "Txt" =>  array('_' => '',"n" => "Agente","v" => "aaa"),
      "Fec" =>  array('_' => '',"n" => "Fecha","v" => "2018-01-24"),
      "Txt" =>  array('_' => '',"n" => "Sesion","v" => "0")
  )
);
```

Webservice return error, only receive 1 param...

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.